# How did the B2 Bomber achieve yaw

Tags: yaw, b-2

[image]

I came across this diagram of the B2. I was wondering how it achieved yaw. If I'm correct usually the rudder on the tail would do this, but the B2 does not have a tail. Does it have no need for yaw, or does something else act as the tail?

Comment: It uses differential air brakes.

Answer (score 0):

They use differential breaking. The elevons are split, and can open up both above and below the wing to increase drag on one side, yawing the plane.